# How to turn off autocomplete for filenames in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, filenames

When you save a file and you start entering in text in the save dialog box, a drop down list of files that begin with the letters you have typed appear. How do you stop the list from appearing?

Answer (score 5):

The key for this rests in a registry setting.

To stop this behavior, just open your registry editor and goto:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > Explorer > AutoComplete

Inside that key are two values that need to be changed: "Append Completion" and "AutoSuggest".

Set both of those to "No" and you should be all set.

Comment: I don't have either of those keys. Is it safe to create them? What type are they? I'm on Windows 7 Pro SP 1.